# SVG textPath animation on Scroll multiple times on a page

Tags: animation, svg, onscroll

I’m trying to get multiple headings on a Shopify homepage to be animated on a svg textPath. My code loads the headings and they each sit on their own svg curved path. However, only one heading is animated on scroll. How do I get each of the headings to be animated on scroll? Do I need multiple window.addEventListener(‘scroll’, onScroll-n) functions for each heading?

```
<script>
 console.clear();

 var textPath = document.querySelector('#text-path');
 var textContainer = document.querySelector('#text-container');
 var path = document.querySelector( textPath.getAttribute('href') );
 var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
 console.log(pathLength);

 function updateTextPathOffset(offset){
   textPath.setAttribute('startOffset', offset); 
 }

 updateTextPathOffset(pathLength);

 function onScroll(){
  requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    var rect = textContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scrollPercent = rect.y / window.innerHeight;
    console.log(scrollPercent);
    updateTextPathOffset( scrollPercent * 2 * pathLength );
  });
 }

 window.addEventListener('scroll',onScroll);
</script>

<svg id="text-container" viewBox="0 0 1000 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="text-curve" d="M0 100s269.931 86.612 520 0c250.069-86.612 480 0 480 0" fill="none"/>
  <text y="40">
    <textPath id="text-path" href="#text-curve" startOffset="200">
      {{ section.settings.title }}
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: all your id values need to be unique on the entire page. I imagine you have multiple id="text-container" and id="text-curve" and id="text-path" elements.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. I just repeated all of it with new variable and function names. It works, though it's constantly cycling. I was hoping to just refactor. But I might have to do a setTimeout instead since its cycling too much.

Comment: To make is easier for people to help you please consider editing your question so that the code is in a snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can do the align animation with SVG SMIL:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL
- Set the values dynamically from your Scroll Event

```html
<svg width="450" height="180">
  <path id="P1" pathLength="200" d="M0 100s270 87 520 0c250-87 480 0 480 0" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="red"/>
  <text>
    <textPath id="P2" href="#P1">
      TEXT
      <animate 
         attributeName="startOffset"
         attributeType="XML"
         values="0;80"
         keyTimes= "0;1"
         dur="2s"
         fill="freeze"
         repeatCount="1"/>
    </textPath>
  </text>
  <animateMotion>
    <mpath href="#P2" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @Danny Engleman.  I will add this and run my code.